# NoClassDefFoundError when using ant

Tags: java, ant, noclassdeffounderror

I am using a project which have declared own ant result formatted.When i build the framework code it builds fine.But when i try to generate the report using that formatter i get 
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error and build fails

```
xyz\build.xml:391: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/
Logger
```

I have the log4j jar in the lib directory when am building the project.Do i need to include some and runtime environment?

If yes how?What else can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the jar file explicitly to the runtime classpath (just as you would do with a directory of class files).